# How to view activity log on Parse.com

Tags: android, class, parse-platform, activitylog

I'm developing a database on Parse and client messed up a Class. He don't remember what he changed and I don't know what was it like before. Can any way we can see activity log of whole db or just that Class?

Answer (score 0):

While i can suggest to use the parse `rollback` for your situation .

Your answer will be using the `parse` command line option you can see any number of lines from the logs ,

```
log [app]
Prints out recent log messages.
-n              The number of the messages to display.  Defaults to 10.
-f              Emulates tail -f and streams new messages from the server
-l, --level     The log level to restrict to.  Can be 'INFO' or 'ERROR'.
                Defaults to 'INFO'.
```